# How can I erase my data from textarea using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i erase my data from textarea using javascript ?

**This code:**

```
<textarea class="mails" tabindex="1" onfocus="this.className='writing'" onblur="this.className='mails'" onkeypress="this.className='writing'" >يمكنك إضافة أكثر من بريد إلكتروني. أضف "," بين كل إدخال</textarea>
```

Comment: The textarea does not contain a name property? Is it only used from javascript or will it be posted to a serverscript, if so, then you need to have a name to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give your textarea an id first

```
<textarea id="txtarea" class="mails" tabindex="1" onfocus="this.className='writing'" onblur="this.className='mails'" onkeypress="this.className='writing'" >يمكنك إضافة أكثر من بريد إلكتروني. أضف "," بين كل إدخال</textarea>
```

and use this in your JS

```
document.getElementById("txtarea").value = "";
```

Comment: thank you but in my textarea i not have "value" i enter text in tag <textarea>TEXXXXXXXT</textarea>

Comment: you can get the contents of a textarea by doing document.getElementById("txtarea").value. Everything between <textarea></textarea> will be returned.

Comment: you have space in here (..value = "" )... the true: (..value ="" )

Comment: @Anas: spaces around the `=` will make no functional difference at all, and are just there for readability.

Comment: @Tim Down, thanks for answering that for me. Yeah as tim said its always good to make your code readable, the behaviour however is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the textarea an ID

```
<textarea id="edit-text" class="mails" tabindex="1" onfocus="this.className='writing'" onblur="this.className='mails'" onkeypress="this.className='writing'" >aldkasdklad al;kd al;kd la;ksd al;kd l;aksl;dkal;skdl aksdl  </textarea>

document.getElementById("edit-text").value = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct way of doing this is by setting the value property to an empty string.
Even if you don't set any property, the browser attaches all the specific properties to an element wen it's added to the dom.
However, if you are sceptic about the ".value" prop , you could try to alter the innerHTML of the element :

```
document.getElementById("edit-text").innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: which doesnt work properly in Internet explorer just on every other browser so innerHtml generally is to be avoided if you want cross browser support.